# Any ideas on how to fix this broken kettle?

Tags: home

Found this kettle morphy richards 108399 broken. 
On the image below, and as any kettle, there is a button to open the top lid. The mechanism is a small stick, shown in picture 2 that pushes the zone named 'Push Inwards' on picture 1.

But the plastic stick falls short, and the kettle remains closed. I'm mostly wondering if there is a piece missed here ( you might have a similar kettle to open :)? ) or maybe I something is not on its place.

Any help will be welcome.

**Picture 1**

[image: Picture 1]

**Picture 2**

[image: picture 2]

Answer (score 2):

Leave the cap of the lid off and manually "push inwards"? It looks like the action needed to open the kettle is compressing the spring so take that action manually. If you can push it too far and the mechanism will become damaged, wind a screw in inhibiting the movement of the U shaped plastic so it cannot be moved so far

Or

Reassemble the kettle and fill it through the spout that you pour the boiling water out of - my father has had the same kettle for 20 years, and has never opened its lid

Comment: The second part is the best approach in its simplicity, imho (+1).